# Hessian is numerically singular with a categorical predictor but not with a continuous one

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-data

Let's say I have a mouse performed a task for several runs, and for each run I assigned a score (ordered). I'm interested in the effects of medication (A, B) across runs.

```
dat.ord <- data.frame(run=rep(seq(1,10,1),times=2), med=rep(c("A","B"),each=10), score=factor(c(0,0,1,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,0), ordered=T)

fm <- clm(score ~ factor(run)*med, data=dat.ord)

Warning message:
(1) Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined 
In addition: Absolute convergence criterion was met, but relative criterion was not met
```

If I treat run as continuous variable, there is no warning:

```
fm <- clm(score ~ run*med, data=dat.ord)
```

I thought ordinal regression was simply an extension of logistic regression, so I was expecting a similar warning if I ran a logistic regression:

```
dat.log <- data.frame(run=rep(seq(1,10,1),times=2), med=rep(c("A","B"),each=10), score=factor(c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0), ordered=T)
fm <- glm(score ~ factor(run)*med, data=dat.log, family="binomial")
```

But there is no warning.

Why am I getting the warning in ordinal regression if I convert `run` into a categorical factor but no warning if `run` is a continuous predictor?